# How to declare a variable within the same statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

How do I create variables in MySQL that I can refer to in the same statement?

Does this work for UPDATE and INSERT statements as well?

I asked this because I got a lot of SQL text files where I execute single commands using Ctrl-Enter from MySQL-Workbench. If it would be multiple statements I would have to select the commands to execute before pressing Ctrl-Enter. This is more complex and error-prone.

Before someone asks: this is a private database with single user and I use these scripts to modify data directly where editing through the GUI would take ages.

I just decided that I should wrap more complex code with a java program.  This was a good decision. Still I need the solution to this question for less complex problems where I don't want to write java code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need to do this in the same statement. It's easy to run two statements, and it makes the code much easier to write and easier to understand. You should always consider how the developer who succeeds you working on your code is going to understand and maintain it.

```
SET @variable = 'Value';

SELECT ... FROM your_table WHERE a_column = @variable;
```

If you do need to do it in one statement, I'd do it this way:

```
SELECT ... FROM your_table 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @variable := 'Value') AS _init
WHERE a_column = @variable;
```

By doing this in a derived-table, it only does the assignment once. If you do it in the select-list as you showed in your solution, it does the assignment as many times as the number of rows returned by the inner query. This is not a big deal if the assignment is for a constant value, but if your variable is assigned the result of a costly expression, it will be slow.

Comment: Well, I have a text file with multiple statements. I execute single statements from this file manually by pressing Ctrl-Enter. If it were multiple statements I would have to select the text to execute first. -- Will try your solution though.

Comment: @JPT None of which appears in your question.

Comment: you are both right. I wrapped the SQL with Java and now I've got trivial SQL statements plus full control over what happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I wasn't able to find a solution on the web. But it turned out to be... fairly straightforward. 
Just create a statement that wraps your statement:

```
select *, @variable:='Value' from (
    select * from your_table inner where @variable=inner.column
) as outer
```